# Can vectors on two planes which are orthogonal produce the same vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let us say we have a vector X. Suppose this vector X is a linear combination of vectors on a plane A, is it possible that it can also be obtained by a linear combination of vectors on plane B, given that these two planes are orthogonal to each other? At least can you tell me how to approach this problem?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I am not sure that what you state is correct. It would be correct if $A$ and $B$ were one the orthogonal subspaces, but orthogonal planes are not orthogonal subspaces. Just consider that their intersection forms a line: any vector on this line is in both spaces at the same time, without being zero.

Comment: If they are orthogonal subspaces would my problem be solved ?

Answer (score 1):

with all the vectors of a plane, with sums, rests and linear combinations of them, the result will always be in the same plane. There is no option that vector leaves this plane. 
You can think on the plane of your floor and the plane of one of your walls. 
Is there any vector which belongs to both?

Comment: The vector that lies on the intersection of these two planes ?

Comment: Yes, and all its multiples (included 0)